# Positioning a control in an absolute position on a form

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a main Xamarin form. The XAML looks like:

```
<AbsoluteLayout x:Name="MyLayout">
    <Button Text="Add Label" 
       HorizontalOptions="Center"
       VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand"
       Clicked="Button_Clicked" />
</AbsoluteLayout>
```

On the code-behind, I'm trying to add a label in a specific position:

```
var newLabel = new Label()
{
    Text = "Hello World"
};

newLabel.Layout(new Rectangle()
{
    Left = 200,
    Top = 200
});

Layout.Children.Add(newLabel);
```

It does add the label, but always at the top left-hand corner of the form. I was sort of under the impression that using an `AbsoluteLayout` meant I could put child controls wherever I wanted, but I'm guessing that's not the case, or there's some secret sauce that I'm missing to setting the position.

Can someone point me in the right direction, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you didn't set bounds and flags, Well for this example setting the flag would be optional since absolute positioning is the default

```
var newLabel = new Label()
{
    Text = "Hello World"
};
AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutBounds (newLabel , new Rectangle (200, 200, 100, 100));
MyLayout.Children.Add(newLabel);
```

[Try visitting this link AbsoluteLayout Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/absolute-layout)